# ASP.NET MVC DevExpress XtraReport with getting parameter from View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress, xtrareport

I want to generate a report that contains data from a database using a filter stored in a ViewData.

My question is how I will pass the ViewData value of the report as a parameter to display some data.

**Controller :**

```
var Soc = (string)TempData["Societe"];


            XtraReport report = new Training.UI.Web.Reporting.Etat1();
            report.DataSource = from p in db.TEntreprises
                                where p.EntNom == Soc
                                select p;

            report.Parameters.Add(new DevExpress.XtraReports.Parameters.Parameter() { Name = "EntNom", Type = typeof(String), Value = Soc, Description = "NomEntreprise" });

            ViewData["Report"] = report;

            return PartialView("DocumentViewerPartial");
```

**View :**

```
@Html.DevExpress().DocumentViewer(settings =>
{

settings.Name = "documentViewer1";
settings.StylesSplitter.SidePaneWidth = 340;

settings.Report = (Training.UI.Web.Reporting.Etat1) ViewData["Report"];

settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Etat1", Action = "DocumentViewerPartial" };
settings.ExportRouteValues = new { Controller = "Etat1", Action = "ExportDocumentViewer" };
}).GetHtml()
```

And I have no data in the XtraReport

Comment: What you have tried so far, can you share your code?

Comment: It is very difficult to read your code in comment. Please modify your question with your code.

Comment: Ok.I's modified.thanks

Answer (score 0):

To apply the values to the report, create a string that contains the report name and the submitted values, and pass this string to the viewer’s OpenReport method.

The example below demonstrates how to do the following:

Create a page with a document viewer and button.
Create a string with the report name and a predefined parameter value and pass this string to the viewer’s OpenReport method on a button click.

Viewer.cshtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function OnClick() {
        var reportName = "XtraReport1";
        var paramName = "strParam";
        var paramValue = "42";
        var reportUrl = reportName + '?' + paramName + '=' + paramValue;

        WebDocumentViewer1.OpenReport(reportUrl);
    }
</script>



@Html.DevExpress().Button(settings => {
    settings.Name = "dxOpenButton";
    settings.Text = "Submit parameter";
    settings.ClientSideEvents.Click = "OnClick";
}).GetHtml()

@Html.DevExpress().WebDocumentViewer(settings => {
    settings.Name = "WebDocumentViewer1";
}).Bind("XtraReport1").GetHtml()
```

When you call the viewer’s OpenReport method, the reporting engine executes a report name resolution service. This service creates a report instance and returns it to the viewer. Implement this service to apply the parameter values to the report. The string argument from the OpenReport method is passed to the service’s method that returns a report instance. In this method, do the following:

Parse the string argument to extract the report name and parameter values.
Create a report instance and apply the parameter values to it. Reference each parameter by name in the report’s Parameters collection and assign the value to the parameter’s Value property.

If you want custom UI elements to be the only way to submit parameter values, hide the Parameters Panel. To do this, disable the Visible property for all report parameters. If you want users to submit parameter values from both the panel and custom UI elements, disable the report’s RequestParameters property.

Return the report instance.
When you create a Web Reporting application from the DevExpress Template Gallery, you can add the Report Storage service to the application. This service will be utilized as a report name resolution service in your application. For this, implement the service’s GetData method as follows:

CustomReportStorageWebExtenstion.CS

```
public override byte[] GetData(string url) {
    try {
        // Parse the string with the report name and parameter values.
        string[] parts = url.Split('?');
        string reportName = parts[0];
        string parametersQueryString = parts.Length > 1 ? parts[1] : String.Empty;

        // Create a report instance.
        XtraReport report = null;

        if (Directory.EnumerateFiles(reportDirectory).
            Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension).Contains(reportName)) {
            byte[] reportBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(reportDirectory, reportName + FileExtension));
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(reportBytes))
                report = XtraReport.FromStream(ms);
        }

        if (report != null) {
            // Apply the parameter values to the report.
            var parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(parametersQueryString);

            foreach (string parameterName in parameters.AllKeys) {
                report.Parameters[parameterName].Value = Convert.ChangeType(
                    parameters.Get(parameterName), report.Parameters[parameterName].Type);
            }

            // Disable the Visible property for all report parameters
            // to hide the Parameters Panel in the viewer.
            foreach (var parameter in report.Parameters) {
                parameter.Visible = false;
            }

            // If you do not hide the panel, disable the report's RequestParameters property.
            // report.RequestParameters = false;

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
                report.SaveLayoutToXml(ms);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception) {
    // ...
}
```

To apply parameter values from a URL query string to a report, implement the viewer’s action method as follows:

Create a report instance and apply the parameter values to it. Reference each parameter by name in the report’s Parameters collection and assign the value to the parameter’s Value property.

If you want a URL’s query string to be the only way to submit parameter values, hide the Parameters Panel. To do this, disable the Visible property for all report parameters. If you want users to submit parameter values from both the panel and a URL’s query string, disable the report’s RequestParameters property.

Return a report view.

The example below demonstrates how to implement the viewer’s action method to apply the parameter value from the query string of the following URL: https://localhost:5001/Home/Viewer?intParam=42.

HomeController.cs

```
public ActionResult Viewer(int? intParam) {
    var report = new XtraReport1();
    report.Parameters["intParam"].Value = intParam;
    report.Parameters["intParam"].Visible = false;
    return View(report);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRnIK.png)